# Why this ajax script doesn't send data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

i'm trying to send a js variable to a php file, to create a query.
Thi is my script, but it doesn't work, could you help me?

```
<select class="form-control" id="Input_Cli" name="Input_Cli" onchange="sendtophp()">
    <option disabled selected value> Seleziona il cliente</option>
    <?php
       $results = pg_query($conn, "SELECT piva, nome FROM cliente");
       while($row = pg_fetch_array($results)) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row['piva']?>"><?php echo $row['nome']?></option>
    <?php
       }
    ?>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
function sendtophp()  { 
    var cli = document.getElementById("Input_Cli").value;
    document.getElementById("prova").innerHTML = cli;
    $.ajax({
        url: "C:\xampp\htdocs\Progetto\getlist.php"
        type: "GET"
        data: {Cli : cli}
        success: function( )
        {
            alert("success!");
        }
    });
} 
</script>
```

Comment: What specifically goes wrong?

Comment: Use a relative path `getList.php` instead of the file path `C:\xampp\htdocs\Progetto\getlist.php`

Comment: It doesn't do anything, for the path i've just tried and seems dosen't matter

Comment: This is my php code `<?php
 $cli = isset($_GET['Cli']);
 echo $cli;
 
 ?>`

Comment: What actually goes wrong? Does the `<select>` populate correctly? Is the JavaScript function called? Does the AJAX fire? Does the success handler fire? What's the response? Are any errors reported?

Comment: For starters: your ajax options have to be comma-separated.

Comment: There are no errors reported, now i have tried to separate the option with comma but it still doesn't work. The select is populate correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested this, your script works quite fine. 
There must be in error in your PHP outputting the options or you are simply calling the wrong url, which we cant check.

The below snippet with your PHP (test.php in the same directory as the html file) on a valid server returns 1 if I change the selectbox.

Make sure you are actually opening the page on your webserver in your browser, not your local file.

For the purpose of this snippet I changed the url to something we can actually validate here.

```js
function sendtophp() {
  var cli = document.getElementById("Input_Cli").value;

  $.ajax({
    url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1",
    type: "GET",
    data: {
      Cli: cli
    },
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="form-control" id="Input_Cli" name="Input_Cli" onchange="sendtophp()">
  <option disabled selected value> Seleziona il cliente </option>
  <option>some option</option>
</select>
```